# Cmake ignoring CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

Tags: debugging, cmake, version, release

I am trying to include debug/release dependent compiler flags, such as:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++0x -Wall -DUSE_BOOST")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CSS_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall -O3")
```

I create my build folder with a command such as:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D UseFortran=True -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.6 ~/repos/cliques/cliques
```

However it seems with CMAKE version 2.8.7, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is being ignored.  It seems to work perfectly with version 2.8.4 (on a different machine), so has this method been deprecated or is there some other problem here?

Zenna

Comment: It's not deprecated.  How are you assessing that it's being ignored?

Comment: No debug symbols  are in the executable, and if I add bad commands e.g. set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall lots of bad commands"), there is no effect.

Comment: Must read: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-September/023808.html

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo. Your code says `CMAKE_CSS_FLAGS_RELEASE`. Notice `CSS`, it should be `CXX`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that there must be a space between the `-D` and the variable. That is, it should be:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D UseFortran=True -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.6 ~/repos/cliques/cliques
```

Comment: And don't forget to define the variable type. From CMake docs, it's: `-D <var>:<type>=<value>`

Comment: I have _never_ had to use a space after -D. Are you sure your `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` contained `-g`? If you re-used the same build directory, it's possible that invalid values in the variable cache were reused.

Comment: Are the build type `RELEASE` and `Release` equivalent?

Comment: Is there a way to force `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in case it wasn't defined on command line?

Answer (score 2):

I think they made a Typo In CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE in the previous version. We had this porblem and here a line that works.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug ../src
```

You may check that every things went fine using:

```
cmake -L ../src
```

Using this command may give you the right way to name the variable CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, when creating build folder? 
Cmake build Release type project or Debug type project, not both together.